# What is the meaning of \+ in doxygen-generated latex?

Tags: macros, errors, symbols

When compiling a software reference manual with doxygen and latex output, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 ... Modular System for Shelves and Coasts (M\+                       
                                                  O\+S\+S\+C\+O, \href{http:...
```

(note that here the line break indicates the position of the error)

1. Latex does not know how to expand '\+'.  Any ideas what this means?
2. Doxygen introduced this '\+' before any intra-word capital letter.  Why and how to get rid of this behavior?
3. How to you search a search machine for that kind of problem (a special escaped character combination like "Latex \+"?

Thank you for any ideas. (especially on point 2.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you double the backlashes?

Comment: In the log fragment you show `\\+` but in the title you show `\+` which is it?

Comment: Sorry Dave, I confused the system with too much escaping.  The problem is the macro "backslash plus"

Comment: Thanks egreg.  No, nod backslash doubling, just too much escaping on my part ...

Comment: There is no standard definition for `\+` in LaTeX, except inside the `tabbing` environment, which is out of question here. There should be some configuration in Doxygen that adds it in those cases, perhaps the intent is to space out all caps words. If you're able to add something like `\newcommand{\+}{\kern0.05em}` or, if you prefer, `\newcommand{\+}{}` to your LaTeX preamble, you should  solve the issue.

Comment: Works (thanks!) as a temporary fix (until someone uses tabbing ...).  Still, I have no clue where and why this macro is introduced by doxygen...

Comment: I have the same issue since I upgraded from doxygen 1.8.6 to 1.8.9.1. In 1.8.6, a \\- was generated instead of \\+. With the \\- it worked fine.

Comment: The command is defined in the main generated file, `refman.tex`: `\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{\scriptsize$\hookleftarrow$}}{}{}}`, which means "you can break a line here, but add a box right at the end of the broken line with the `\hookleftarrow` sign in the math mode". In other words, `\+` marks an optional line break, and and a very ugly one. Why does Doxygen thinks that `Open\+FS\+T` are good places for optional word breaks, I have no idea. To add an i. to an i., the command is placed into a non-customizable file, past your customizations. I perl it into `\newcommand{\+}{}`. YMMV.